# Get Node Id of Umbraco content

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

I am creating a `select` element list from Umbraco content

I can navigate to the nodes I want to get the data from (`benCatItem` below) - when at `benCatItem`, how do I get the Id of the element? When I debug, I can see it under `Content` as an int of Id - but cannot work out how to set a variable as the value

```
@{ foreach (var benCat in Model.Content.Children (c=>c.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("benefitCategory", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
                {
                    string catLabel = benCat.GetPropertyValue<string>("benefitCategoryLabel");
                    <optgroup label="@catLabel">
                        @{ foreach (var benCatItem in benCat.Children)
                            {

                                string catItemLabel = benCatItem.GetPropertyValue<String>("BenefitCategoryItemLabel");
                                string catItemLinkURL = benCatItem.GetPropertyValue<String>("BenefitCategoryItemLinkURL");
                                string catItemLinkText = benCatItem.GetPropertyValue<String>("BenefitCategoryItemLinkText");
```

I need the Id to populate the value of the select option for reference purposes

Comment: Could you not just do `var catItemId = benCatItem.Id;`?

Comment: Thanks! Can you make this an answer so I can tick it?

Comment: You're welcome!  Just posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `benCatItem` variable is an instance of `IPublishedContent` so you should be able to access the **Id** property as follows:

```
var catItemId = benCatItem.Id;
```

For a complete list of the default Umbraco properties please see the official docs:
https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/ipublishedcontent/Properties